# how to add spacer in toolbar using vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I am following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/pbU9JxMriOo?t=406) and I want to use `v-spacer` to give space between the title and button. The `<v-spacer> </v-spacer>` no longer works as shown in the tutorial. On Vuetify documentation, it only applies for grid system. Does it mean the new version of Vuetify only allow 'v-spacer' for giving spaces to rows and columns? And what are the alternatives I can use to give space in the toolbar? Thank you!

Comment: The [Vuetify Docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars/#dense-toolbars) do use `v-spacer` in a `v-toolbar`.

Comment: can you please share some code of what you have done so this question could be better understood and reviewed?